# How to run SqlDataReader and SqlDataAdapter concurrently?

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

How do I correct the code so that the exception will not appear again?

```
SqlConnection
    sqlCnn = new SqlConnection("Connection String");

SqlCommand
    sqlCmdSelect = new SqlCommand("SQL SELECT statement;", sqlCnn),
    sqlCmdUpdate = new SqlCommand("SQL UPDATE statement;", sqlCnn);

Thread
    t1 = new Thread(()=>{
        SqlDataReader sdr;
        while(true)
        {
            sdr = sqlCmdSelect.ExecuteReader();
            // Do some works
            sdr.Close();
        }
    }),
    t2 = new Thread(()=>{
        SqlDataAdapter sda;
        while(true)
        {
            using(sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                // Do some works
                sda.UpdateCommand = sqlCmdUpdate;
                if(!sdr.IsClosed) sdr.Close();
                sda.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    });

t1.Start();
t2.Start();
```

System.InvalidOperationException: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the first place? It *won't* make your code run faster, it will probably result in blocking or deadlocks. Simply using `SqlDataAdapter` for updates reduces performance significantly. Whatever you want to do it's probably easier to do in SQL or using the proper technologies like bulk insert or batched updates

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place and why do you want to read and update at the same time? Perhaps all you need is a single `UPDATE FROM .... WHERE...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can have multiple operations on single connection by using [MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets):

> Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is a feature that works with SQL
>   Server to allow the execution of multiple batches on a single
>   connection. When MARS is enabled for use with SQL Server, each command
>   object used adds a session to the connection.

to enable it simply modify your connection string by adding `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` to it like so:

```
Data Source=MSSQL1;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

No other code changes are required yet remember it is a configuration change so if you have some environments setup like test, staging you need to propagate this change to those environments as well.

Answer (score 0):

As exception says, you can't execute two operations on the same connection.

I would just create two objects of `SqlConnection` class and use them separately in threads.

Alternatively, you could use some synchronization on executing SQL statements (`lock`, `Semaphore`) but it would be totally opposite to what you want to do.